# Activity cannot be cast to android.app.Application

Tags: java, android, classcastexception

When I start the application, it **force close**.

This is the **LogCat**:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate application com.blocktrekacademy.officialblocktrek.Authentication: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.blocktrekacademy.officialblocktrek.Authentication cannot be cast to android.app.Application
```

[**UPDATED**] : This is my **AndroidManifest.xml**:

```
    ...
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity
            android:name=".Authentication"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_authentication"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

This is my **Authentication.java**

```
package com.blocktrekacademy.officialblocktrek;

import ...

public class Authentication extends AppCompatActivity {
    ...
```

Comment: Well what does the declaration of `com.blocktrekacademy.officialblocktrek.Authentication` look like?

Comment: Does `com.blocktrekacademy.officialblocktrek.Authentication` extends `Application`?

Comment: It extends AppCompatActivity

Comment: An `Activity` is not an `Application`. Activities go in `<activity>` elements in the manifest. Only `Application` subclasses can be specified in `<application>`. Are you sure you need an `Application` at all?

Comment: When I remove the `android:name` in the **AnroidManifest.xml**, it outpus me an error,  `have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml`

Comment: Every Activity must be declared in the Manifest. In the proper section.

Answer (score 1):

First, remove `android:name=".Authentication"` property in `<application>` tag.

Your `Authentication` class is an `Activity`, not an `Application`. So, you have to declare it as such:

```
<application>

    ...

    <activity android:name=".Authentication"
      <intent-filter>
          <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
          <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
      </intent-filter>
    </activity>

</application>
```

That `intent-filter` declares the Activity as the "main" activity, so it will be launched when your app starts.

Comment: Well I removed the android:name and it throws me `java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.blocktrekacademy.officialblocktrek/com.blocktrekacademy.officialblocktrek.Authentication}: android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {/com.blocktrekacademy.officialblocktrek.Mainpage}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?`

Comment: What is com.blocktrekacademy.officialblocktrek.Mainpage?

Comment: That is where I redirect the user after they log in.

Comment: You have to declare that Activity in the AndroidManifest, too.

Comment: I've declared it but it says that the question is mostly code so I removed it.